# UITableView problem displaying contents of multiple sections

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a table view which displays contents of several possible sections. The problem I am having is that when a section does not appear at the top of the screen and the user has to scroll to it, for some reason the contents of the first section are displayed in the cell label. When the item is selected, it loads the proper data, it just doesn't display correctly in the table view. Here is the cell code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    Sections *thisSection = [self.sectionsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];

    NSArray *sectionMedia = [NSArray arrayWithArray:[thisSection.media allObjects]];

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor1 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"releaseDate" ascending:NO];
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor2 = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"sortKey" ascending:YES];
    NSArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor1, sortDescriptor2, nil];
    sectionMedia = [sectionMedia sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    Media *thisMedia = [sectionMedia objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    [NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"MMM d, yyyy"];
    NSString *articleDisplayDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:thisMedia.releaseDate];

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        cell.textLabel.text = thisMedia.title;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = articleDisplayDate;
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    }

    [dateFormatter release];
    [sortDescriptors release];
    [sortDescriptor1 release];
    [sortDescriptor2 release];

    return cell;
}
```

When I print a log outside the if block "if (cell == nil)" it appears to show the correct data at all times. However, when I place the log inside this block it does not log the data from the out of view section, and when I scroll down to the data it does nothing - so it seems like it's not seeing that cell data as nil and assigning it the data from the first section.

Comment: A problem I see with this code is that you only set the cell contents when you create a new cell, i.e. inside `if (cell == nil)` and not when you reuse an already existing cell via `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. So, in this case you get a cell with old contents and you don't set the "right" contents.

Comment: Thanks for this response - so, do you suggest removing the if block?

Comment: That actually did fix the problem. That code is what is there by default when I create a table view, so my assumption was that it saved resources. Seems that it was working against me in this instance. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't suggest removing the if block but moving some statements out of it. I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it (if you want to).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A problem I see with this code is that you only set the cell contents when you create a new cell, i.e. inside `if (cell == nil)` and not when you reuse an already existing cell via `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier`. So, in this case you get a cell with old contents and you don't set the "right" contents. I suggest moving some statements out of the if block:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}
cell.textLabel.text = thisMedia.title;
cell.detailTextLabel.text = articleDisplayDate;
```

Comment: Another thing you should probably do, when you get the deQueued cell is to reset all the cell contents to empty before you fill in the new values.  The reason to do this is that you might get leftover values from the previous use of that cell that would cause it to display incorrectly if you don't reset those first.